# Query de filtro de fechas no da resultado esperado

Tags: php, mysqli

Mi intención es conseguir listar una serie de productos, especificando un rango de fechas de intención de reserva,y filtrando así los productos todavía no reservados.

```
$comprobar_reservas_disponibilidad = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT flotaid 
                FROM disponibilidad 
                WHERE ('$fecha_inicio' BETWEEN DESDE AND HASTA) AND ('$fecha_fin' BETWEEN DESDE AND HASTA) ORDER BY flotaid");


$comprobar_prereservas = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT flotaid 
            FROM prereserva 
            WHERE ('$fecha_inicio' BETWEEN DESDE AND HASTA) AND ('$fecha_fin' BETWEEN DESDE AND HASTA) ORDER BY flotaid");
```

Imaginemos que la informacion de las dos queries se guarda en un array del que se extrae la info.

Utilizo dos queries por que cada una de ellas pertenece a una tabla.En las dos figura informacion de reserva,pero cada una es rellenada de una forma,eso es igual.

¿Cómo es posible que la query de el resultado correcto para un rango de fechas pequeño,pero no para uno grande? 
El resultado listado solamente debería ser cada vez más pequeño,ya que se pide un rango de fechas mayor que abarca productos ya reservados,no es así?

Utilizo tres tablas,**"prereserva"** y **"disponibilidad"**,que se utilizan para guardar los datos de las reservas,y **"flota"**,donde se guarda la información descriptiva de los barcos..nombre,características,modelo..etc. Los datos del usuario que hace la reserva desde la web,se guardan en "prereserva" hasta que pasen unos dias o el admin de la web lo pase mediante otro programa a la tabla "disponibilidad",que es la de reservas definitivas.Yo necesito rellenar "prereserva" con los datos del rango de fechas a reservar,barco,usuario a reservar.

paso enlace a archivo completo :  ["Codigo completo"](http://txt.do/d5q1j)

e imagen de lo que devuelve un rango de fechas : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt7G1.jpg

*ejemplo* : barcos no disponibles entre los días 25/11/2016 y 25/11/2016 :Ids  8,15,17 ,asi pues,se listan los demás,los disponibles

Lo que necesito en una query (que utilizaré en dos ocasiones) para obtener las ids de los barcos SI DISPONIBLES,y filtrar los NO DISPONIBLES,que se le mostraran en un print/echo para saber qué se ha filtrado.

Comment: En tu ejemplo, ¿cual es el resultado que obtienes?

Comment: En mi ejemplo real,busco entre '24-11-2016' y '24-11-2016' y lista 'Barcos no disponibles:8,15,17,27,29,30,31,32,33,34,16' y si busco desde '24-11-2016' hasta '30-11-2016',se lista '8,15,17'..

Comment: Y entiendo que sólo tendría que aparecer uno de los barcos en vez de tres en el segundo rango ¿no?

Comment: A mi parecer,cuantos más días se pidan para reservar,más dificil será por que más barcos habrá reservados,por lo que en el segundo rango deberían de aparecer los mismos que en el primero,más los de los días extra.

Comment: La pregunta no es clara, en parte porque tienes 2 tablas, pero luego no sé de cual de las 2 te refieres cuando citas tus ejemplos. Pero sobre todo, porque no tenemos conocimiento de tus datos. Lo ideal sería que [modifiques tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/29480/edit) para incluir una muestra de tus datos de ambas tablas, y luego presentarnos los resultados *actuales* de tus queries y también los resultados *deseados*. Si lo presentas de esa forma, será muy fácil entender la pregunta y la causa de tu problema.

Comment: Cuando tienes prisa y te ponen en espera la pregunta -thumbs up-

Answer (score 0):

Prueba haciendo las consultas de la siguiente forma:

```
$fechaDesde = '2015-10-24';
$fechaHasta = '2016-10-24';

$consulta = 'SELECT DISTINCT flotaid 
    FROM disponibilidad 
    WHERE fecha BETWEEN "'.$fechaDesde.'" AND "'.$fechaHasta.'"
    ORDER BY flotaid ASC';
$comprobar_reservas_disponibilidad = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);

$consulta = 'SELECT DISTINCT flotaid 
    FROM prereserva 
    WHERE fecha BETWEEN "'.$fechaDesde.'" AND "'.$fechaHasta.'"
    ORDER BY flotaid ASC';
$comprobar_prereservas = mysqli_query($con, $consulta);
```